# CSS3 transform: translate3d doesn't affect the z-axis?

Tags: css, transform, translate3d

I have this snippet implemented:

**CSS**

```
div
{
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.block
{
    background:#fc0; /* YELLOW */
    top:50px;
    left:50px;
    width:80px;
    height:40px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate3d(1,0,0,-55deg) rotate3d(0,0,1,30deg);
}
.block .part
{
    background:#444; /* GREY */
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,50px);
}
.block:hover .part
{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px,10px,20px); /* ONLY TRANSFORMS X & Y */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="part"></div>
</div>
```

Check out **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kriem/H6JZN)** for the live example.

As you can see, the translation on `:hover` only affects the `.part` on the **x-** and **y-axis**.

**It won't translate in the z-direction.**

Anyone who knows what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it. Forgot to add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;`