# How to add css 3dtransform property with jquery to a dom element?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I'm trying to optimize animations with jquery for IOS mobile devices. There is this known issue of using the 3d-rendering engine which i want to take into account!

Now i want to do some transformations like this:

```
$('.class').css({"-webkit-transform:":"translate3d(200px, 200px, 0px)"});
```

But this doesn't work! No css is added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the rest of your code, did you apply a `-webkit-transition`? Otherwise the effect would happen almost immediately.

The below works fine for me  (working jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/RQzn6/)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="box">Hello</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 100px;
}

#box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
}
```

jQuery

```
$("#box").click(function() {
    $(this).css({'-webkit-transform':'translate3d(200px, 200px, 0px)',
                 '-webkit-transition': 'all 1s ease-out'});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I discovered [Transit](https://github.com/rstacruz/jquery.transit) yesterday, you might find it easier if you don't mind adding a library.

Comment: For most of the stuff I think you have to use .animate.

Answer (score 0):

Have you forgot to add

```
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;  ??
```

You have to add [preserve 3d also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835415/css3-transform-translate3d-doesnt-affect-the-z-axis) .

Comment: Sorry.. :( no clues.In my case i forgot that and searched half google :)